# AngularJS: Get selected Item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http, http-put

I have an ng-repeat that display users in rows, when a user is clicked, it open modal popup for edit User containing all user details. When I select another role for the user and tries to get the newly selected row so as to pass to http put, it does not give the newly selected item text instead it still return the old text

//display users in table rows, click on username to edit

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in usersData | filter: searchBox">

        <td><a ng-click="openEditUser($index)">{{item.UserName}}</a></td>
        <td>{{item.EMail}}</td>
        <td>{{item.RoleName}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">{{item.IsActive ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>

 </tr>
```

When the modal popup opens, I get all the roles from API and add it to `<select>` field

//get all roles and add to select field

```
$http.get('mydomain.com/api/Users/GetAllRole').then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.myData = {};
            $rootScope.myData = response.data;
        });
```

// Here ng-model="selectedItem.RoleId"

```
<select ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedItem.RoleId" class="form-control"
                ng-options="item._id as item.RoleName for item in myData">
            <option value="">Select</option>                                


</select>
```

Here when I choose another role for the user in the `<select>` field and try to get $scope.selectedItem.RoleId it gives the new selected RoleId but when I try to get $scope.selectedItem.RoleName from the `<select>` field it doesn't give the new selected item instead it still returns the old selected item

```
$scope.EditUser = function(){

    $http.put("domain.com/api/Users/UpdateUser", {
       _id: $scope.selectedItem._id,'RoleId': $scope.selectedItem.RoleId, 'EMail': $scope.selectedItem.EMail, RoleName : $scope.selectedItem.RoleName, IsActive: $scope.selectedItem.IsActive

    }).then(function (response) {
        $route.reload();
        $scope.ok();
        $scope.simpleSuccess();
    }, function (error) {
        $scope.ok();
        $scope.simpleError();
    });


  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is due to the wrong `ng-model`given to your `ng-repeat`. The model used here is `selectedItem.RoleId`.

`Angular` will only update the `RoleId` field of your object instead of the whole object. You should set the `ng-model` to `selectedItem`.

```
<select ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedItem" class="form-control" ng-options="item._id as item.RoleName for item in myData">
    <option value="">Select</option>                                
</select>
```

Unfortunately, you didn't provide any JSFiddle so I can't check that this is actually the source of the problem.

**EDIT**

To have the old role selected, you have to set it to the corresponding entrance of the array returned by the API.

I created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24465/) so you can see how to properly use the `ng-select` directive.

Comment: I want the old selected role to be automatic selected in the <select> field when the I click on user to edit so that I can then select another role for the user .  If i use  ng-model="selectedItem"  although it works but it does not automatically select the old role in the <select> field

Comment: @user3055606 check out my edit that will show you how to use the `ng-select`

Comment: do you mean i will have to pass  the selected index to    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.myData[0];

Comment: I guess the old selected value came from your API, so you'll have to recover the index corresponding to this old selected value and do something like `$scope.selectedItem = $scope.myData[index of old value]`