# AngularJS: Selected Id is not passed to the Service

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

To edit the user information ,when I change the role of user and submit the form, the old "id" is passed to the service, however when I change the role ,it shows the id is changed (I print it on the screen

Selected Value is : {{selectedItemvalue}}

).
but still old "id" is passed like if the user role is admin with id number 2 and if I change it to user with id number 1, role id 1 should be passed instead of 2 but the old one which is 2 is passed.

I have checked below post but it didn't work out.
[AngularJS: Get selected Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055110/angularjs-get-selected-item)

```
     <div class="col-md-7">
            <select ng-model="selectedItemvalue">
             <option ng-repeat="role in roless" ng-       selected="selectedItemvalue ==  role.id"
            value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected Value is : {{selectedItemvalue}}</p>
     </div>

        <form ng-submit="submitUserForm(user.id)" name="myForm"
                class="form-horizontal">
```

app.controller('usersDetailsController',
          function($rootScope,$scope,$http,

```
      $location,$routeParams,$route) {

       if ($rootScope.authenticated && $rootScope.role=="ADMIN") {

        $scope.roless = [{"id": 1, "name": "USER"}, {"id": 2,  "name":"ADMIN"}];

        $scope.userId = $routeParams.id;
        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/' + $scope.userId
        }).then(function (response) {

        $scope.user = response.data;
        $scope.selectedItemvalue = $scope.user.roles[0].id;
        console.log("CurrentRole..."+ $scope.selectedItemvalue);
        console.log("Current data of user..."+           JSON.stringify(response.data));});


         $scope.submitUserForm = function (userId) {

         $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/' + userId,
            data: $scope.user

         }).then(
            function (response) {
                console.log("Updated Role data..."+ JSON.stringify(response.data));
                $location.path("/list-all-users");
                $route.reload();
                },
                function (errResponse) {
                $scope.errorMessage = "Error while updating User - Error Message: '" + errResponse.data.errorMessage;
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is the datatype. This expression `value="{{role.id}}"` targets the `string` datatype. So assign the user id like below,

```
$scope.selectedItemvalue = ''+$scope.user.roles[0].id;
```

Comment: changed it as you said but didn't work...still old id is passed.

Comment: Working example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBSMPV6XNTJI

Comment: This exactly is happening but the problem happens when I select the new role and submit the form and receive the old id.

Comment: Hmmm..Please include your piece of code for submitting the form. It will help us to figure out the issue.

Comment: While submitting the form, where you are passing the selected role Id `selectedItemvalue `?

Comment: Yes...selectedItemvalue

Comment: No, I am asking you man... In 'PUT' method, where you are passing the variable `selectedItemvalue ` ?

Comment: I pass it to a service to update the user...public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") final Long id, @RequestBody User user)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't  get any clue from your question and your comments. Try to create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

In your code can you check **$scope.selectedItemvalue = $scope.user.roles[0].id;**. Because of this you set 0th role to $scope.selectedItemvalue and latest value gets override.

Comment: it seems the initial role id which is coming from database never changes when I edit the role from admin to user or vise versa and submit the form, still the initial one is sent to back-end service.

Comment: Which variable you are passing for submiting form?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where the problem is and issue solved by adding below line of    code to $scope.submitUserForm...  actually when you submit the form, it needs to get the id from ng-model and set it to user's role id like this...
$scope.user.roles[0].id = $scope.selectedItemvalue;